# How to add an array to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I've managed to get the marks from the exam and coursework to add up together and get an average. I realized this is what needs to happen.

```
computed module mark = ((coursework mark * coursework weighting) + (examination mark * (100 - coursework weighting))) / 100
```

So, I need to make 2 arrays (if I'm correct), each having the weighting of each module, then do those calculations. How do I add an array to an array that already exists?
This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    computeResults();
}
public static void part1 (){

    double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
    double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};

    System.out.println ("These are the exam marks and the course work marks");//First row is the exam marks, second row is the course work marks
    computeMarks (examMarks);
    computeMarks1 (courseworkmarks);

}
public static void computeMarks(double[] examMarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<examMarks.length;row++){
            System.out.print (examMarks[row] +"\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
public static void computeMarks1(double[] courseworkmarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<courseworkmarks.length;row++){
            System.out.print (courseworkmarks[row] +"\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
public static void computeResults()
{
     double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
        double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};

        double avgMarks[] =new double[examMarks.length];

        for(int i=0;i<avgMarks.length;i++){
            avgMarks[i]=(examMarks[i]+courseworkmarks[i])/2;

        System.out.println(avgMarks[i]);
        }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you're adding two arrays correctly in that last `for` loop in `computeResults`. What is it that you are facing an issue with? Are you getting some error? Or an unexpected result?

Comment: i got the average instead of the total of all them and return it for each, now i need to get the total of that, add all 6 different results and produce a result out of 100, for like an overall mark for a full year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    double examMarks [] = {50,40,60,80,70,11};
    double courseworkmarks [] = {65,49,58,77,35,40};
    System.out.println ("These are the exam marks and the course work marks");//First row is the exam marks, second row is the course work marks
    computeMarks (examMarks);
    computeMarks1 (courseworkmarks);
    System.out.println ("These are the final marks");
    computeResults(examMarks, courseworkmarks);
}

public static void computeMarks(double[] examMarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<examMarks.length;row++){
            System.out.print (examMarks[row] +"\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
public static void computeMarks1(double[] courseworkmarks)
{
    for (int row=0;row<courseworkmarks.length;row++){
            System.out.print (courseworkmarks[row] +"\t");
        }
    System.out.println("\n");
    }


public static void computeResults(double[] examMarks, double[] courseworkmarks)
{

        double avgMarks[] =new double[examMarks.length];

        for(int i=0;i<avgMarks.length;i++){
        int cwWeighting=40;
            avgMarks[i]=(examMarks[i]*(100-cwWeighting)+courseworkmarks[i]*cwWeighting)/100;

        System.out.print (avgMarks[i] +"\t");
        }
}
```

Comment: 1 more question, is there any way i could make a short cut for the 2 arrays that i have? like they are in Part1, and computeMarks method. is there a way to make a shortcut? so i dont have to change both when i need the marks to change? (just answer on this thread)

Comment: Are you saying you want to read them in from a file or something?  If so, that's a new question entirely, and you might like to either post it as a new question, or have a look around at the plethora of similar questions that already exist on this site.

Comment: thanks man, that was great. it made it much simpler and neater :D

Comment: i added a few more codes in there, for it to print out the title of what the numbers meant. thanks again for your help

Comment: 1 more thing, im sorry to bother you again.

Comment: no problem. you may change the code to make the display more beautiful

Comment: i'm puzzled again, im trying to get the avgMarks and divide them by the module amount and give and get the answer. how do i do that? do i need to make another double? i need to give it rules as in 
     if(avgMarks<40)
     {
       System.out.println ("Failed");
      else;
      {
       System.out.println ("pass");
      }
      }

Comment: which 'module amount' you referring to? maybe you can ask new question